# jQuery - detect if child has input

Tags: jquery, html

my html code looks like this

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text">
      <p>X</p>
  </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <p>x</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is:

1. If input has focus, then show next paragraph.
2. If input lost its focus, hide next paragprah.
3. If div.inputs has more than one inputs, do not hide paragraph until one of them loose focus.

I created this jQuery code for it

```
$(".inputs p").hide();

$(".inputs").focusin(function () {
  $(this).find("p").slideDown();
});

$(".inputs").focusout(function () {
  $(this).find("p").slideUp();
});
```

It works, but for div.inputs with more than one input it starting hiding paragraph and then it starting display it again.

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Niet the Dark Absol, I would advocate for using CSS whenever possible (also for animations). But if you really need to handle this via jQuery for a reason, you can simply add `.stop()` in order to prevent the up/down animations when changing focus between inputs inside the same inputs group.

```js
$(".inputs p").hide();

$(".inputs").focusin(function () {
  $(this).find("p").stop().slideDown();
});

$(".inputs").focusout(function () {
  $(this).find("p").stop().slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text">
      <p>X</p>
  </div>
    <div class="inputs">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <p>x</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use JavaScript for CSS's job.

```css
.inputs>p {
    display: none;
}
.inputs>input:focus~p {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still would like to find out how to deal with it with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('p').hide();
$("input[type=text]").focusin(function() {
    $(this).parents("div.inputs").find('p').show();
});
$("input[type=text]").focusout(function() {
    $(this).parents("div.inputs").find('p').hide();
});
})
```